# Interswitch payment gateway integration

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, payment-gateway

I want to integrate `Interwitch payment gateway` in Joomla or wordpress.

Has anyone do this before.

I search and found one extension below for joomla vm but it's payed and i don't know it is the same what I exactly want.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-payment-systems/15132

Is any ither option or i have to go on core ?

Comment: Ask the owner of that extension, there must be some refund policy or trial or any demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interswitch or gtpay integration is not only creating working module like we do on paypal. but we must make customization on the e-commerce script to meet document integration from Interswitch. For example, we must provide transaction reference 6 to 16 digits, providing contact page, etc. so we cannot use standard flow like paypal payment gateway. if you buy ready module on in http://softdb.eu/gtpay-gtbank-magento-payment-gateway-p-34.html, you still need programmer to customize it to meet interswitch integration document (Merchant Acceptance Test Document that referred to as DIY or UAT document). Interswitch is suck and they don't run on standard way and they force us to customize any e-commerce system to work with their scenario; something that don't need on most payment gateway.

I hope it's helping you. you can also read more explanation here http://satoewarna.com/page/index/gtpay-interswitch-gateway-for-oscommerce-magento-or-other-estore-system.html

Answer (score 0):

You can read this tutorial here:
http://tuts.stackarena.com/2012/05/integrating-your-website-with-interswitch-webpay-concluding-part-part-2/

If you require the service, you could go here:
http://e-magin.net/interswitchgtpay-integration/